# Creating Jar files, duplicate Classpath

Tags: java, jar

If I am creating `superjar.jar` and it needs a jar file `stellar.jar` I need to add the following line to the manifest file for superjar.jar
`Class-Path: path/to/stellar.jar`. But in my classpath I already have `stellar.jar`. So whats the deal here? Why can't `superjar.jar` attempt to look up the location of `stellar.jar` from my classpath?

Comment: Is `superjar.jar` a runnable jar file? In that case it needs it in the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to add the following line to the manifest file for superjar.jar Class-Path: path/to/stellar.jar.

You need that path in your superjar, if the environment variable CLASSPATH is ignored, and it is ignored, if you use the superjar as executable jar, and start it with

```
java -jar superjar.jar
```

superjar.jar can access the classpath, if it is started without overriding the classpath with an different ad hoc classpath, and without the technik of running an executable jar, which always just uses the CLASSPATH inside that jar, and always ignores additional attempts of classpaths.

```
CLASSPATH=/foo/bar/superjar.jar:/opt/some/stellar.jar 
java somepackage.SomeClass
```

Wether the classpath is relative or absolute is a different, unrelated discussion. Above example uses Unix/Linux-Syntax. On Windows you would use backslashes and as delimiter ";".

Comment: So basically what your saying is that the class path specified on the command line is always ignored when using an executable jar file? Instead the class path is always derived in this context from the manifest file? It seems that this is the case. In a non executable context is this relaxed, so that I don't need to specify the dependencies in the manifest file as long as I specify them with the -classpath switch?

Comment: Yes, if I understand you right. You may - even if you have an executable jar - run the (or run one of the) program(s) by `java -cp /foo/bar/superjar.jar:/opt/some/stellar.jar somepackage.SomeClass`, if you add all mandatory classes that way. It might be interesting, mainly to use an updated version of some buggy JDBC-Driver for example, or a faster XML-Parser.

Answer (score 0):

If CLASSPATH means an environment variable, then you're about to learn that Java, all IDEs, and all Java EE app servers ignore it.

I don't have CLASSPATH environment variable on any machine that I work on, because it's useless.  You need to learn how to set CLASSPATH properly without depending on an environment variable.

Comment: Nope I'm not using any environment variable here. Thanks for the heads up though I usually forget that one with much confusion.

Comment: Whups. No thats incorrect because I actually use the CLASSPATH environment variable on two of my machines here. So its not ignored, just not advisable. The confusion usually comes from when I don't do an 'export CLASSPATH' in my .bashrc ;)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The path to stellar.jar is relative to superjar.jar
2. If stellar.jar is already in the classpath, it is in the classpath irrespective of what superjar.jar's manifest says.

Comment: At least in the context of EXECUTING superjar.jar it would seem from my tests over here that you need to have stellar.jar inside the manifest file. I erased it from the manifest file and then ran java -cp /path/to/stellar.jar superjar.jar and it failed. It only worked when I included Class-Path : /path/to/stellar.jar inside the manifest.

Comment: That means your runtime classpath that includes superjar.jar does *not* include stellar.jar

Comment: Well yeah, thats the problem and its because stellar.jar is not inside the manifest file (the manifest file Class-path directive apparently dictates the classpath of an executable jar file)

Comment: To be more clear, it seems that even if I try to provide the necessary dependency with -classpath or -cp it does not matter. The manifest is the be all and end all for defining dependencies for an executable jar.